# choosing d3JS with Angular vs d3JS with jQuery

Tags: jquery, angularjs, d3.js

I want to develop charts with d3JS library with Jquery . But I saw some of the articles/posts about using d3JS with Angular . I'm also familiar with Angular coding .  Looking at it for first time seems complicated procedure to me when compared with using d3JS & jQuery . So what are benefits of choosing one of the method. And which of method is appropriate to choose in which situation.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can't speak for other down-voters, but this question looks very open-ended. Maybe if you can specify why you are having a hard time choosing one or the other, and more about what you are trying to do? In what context will you use these charts? Why do you need to develop them "with" jQuery or Angular at all?

Comment: IMO, you should not worry of using `angular` or `jQuery` along with `d3`. It is a standalone JS library based on data standing on its own and has **NO Dependency** of other js frameworks. It has its own [rich set of API](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/API-Reference) which has almost everything to play with. It depends up on your application design as well. `D3` will play nice with either of them but again you really do not have to worry about that.

Answer (score 2):

Angular's d3.js implementation provides directives and the expected binding you would want. For a fuller discussion see this article ...
http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/d3-on-angular.html

jQuery provides the normal approach of integrating with the charting library using events, etc - In angular you might instead use a watch, for example

Hope this provides an initial insight

Comment: Awesome link the one you've provided. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is highly subjective. But I will try to answer.

AngularJs is a popular client side MVC library. It has some very good bindings for D3.js in form of directives. However since you seem to be new you should know that AngularJS has a pretty decent learning curve. Also AngularJS team has been busy working on AngularJS 2.0. This version won’t be a complex major update, rather a rewrite of the entire framework and will include breaking changes! However Angular js has a strong community and support should be available in near future. Frameworks have pros and cons of their own.

I would suggest if your project is a complex one page application with lots of input parameters that may change the view (rendered html) then you should definitely go for some client side framework like AngularJs. You may also explore other frameworks like ReactJs for building your UI. ReactJs is relatively new but has gained a lot of support in the community.

If you decide against using a framework do have a look at c3.js which is a charting library based on d3.js. If you want to use simple charts for data visualization C3.js will make your work much easier.

In the end the choice of using or not using a framework largely depend on your use case.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if it will be helpful: We are using a very complex library called sigma.js and both jquery and angular. And when dealing with only events which are themselves defined in the sigma library, and not necessarily data changing in the DOM based on user input, angular is not necessary a plus compared to jquery which interacts with DOMs surgically and efficiently. But when there is a quite a bit of data in the DOM to handle, refresh update, angular stores the model data neatly. Our rule has been: is event coming from sigma library and no data model change? ==> jquery.  The last thing is that sometimes the order of directives does not correspond to the order they are actually loaded in the page, that had created a few problems at initialization, i.e. looking for DOM which was actually not loaded yet...